# How do I use wget in cron?

Tags: php, magento, curl, cron, wget

How do I convert these three cron lines to use `wget` (or even `curl` if that's better) instead of `php`? These cron items [are required](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#create-the-cron-job) to keep Magento 2 up to date.

```
* * * * * php -c /home/example/etc/php.ini /home/example/public_html/bin/magento cron:run
* * * * * php -c /home/example/etc/php.ini /home/example/public_html/update/cron.php
* * * * * php -c /home/example/etc/php.ini /home/example/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Here's as close as I can get to guessing what to do... the middle line seems like it should work but doesn't and I have no idea what to use for the others.

```
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.example.com/???? > /dev/null
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.example.com/update/cron.php > /dev/null
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.example.com/???? > /dev/null
```

Comment: Any special reason to use wget or curl ? Magento itself recommends using the php command.

Comment: I have multiple versions of PHP installed. The PHP version set to be used by the www user in Virtualmin (similar to CPanel) doesn't get reflected to things run by cron. I believe that cron still defaults to the default version of PHP that is installed in my os... for CentOS 7 that is PHP 5.4. Since wget and curl are used by the www user that guarantees I am using the same version of PHP for everything. Here's another Magento developer company that explains it better. http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

Comment: Here's at least one thought on this topic from Magento's Lead Developer, Alan Kent... https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Is-it-possible-to-use-wget-instead-of-php-in-cron-for-Magento-2/m-p/23817#M126

Comment: First article is not related to Magento 2. For the reason of your second line not working is that there is an htaccess file in that directory which prevents cron.php to be run via browser, something that wget or curl would mimic. I'll look around for more details about this issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right... that first article was written with Magento 1.x in mind. I was using that as a pattern to try to figure out how to do it for Magento 2.x but as of yet it seems it may not be possible unless the Magento core team decides modify the core as [Alan and his team are discussing](https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Is-it-possible-to-use-wget-instead-of-php-in-cron-for-Magento-2/m-p/23817#M126). Thoughts?

Comment: Well, as you figured, there is no way you could run those crons via wget or curl as long as Magento core team doesn't want you to. Even if you figure out some way to run the middle one, remaining 2 are coded to be run via shell. As you said that there are multiple versions of PHP installed, you should identify the .ini file responsible for your web shop and is being used by www user. You should be easily able to instruct PHP to use that php.ini file. Also, you won't be able to just run the script via php command, you'll need to locate the installation directory for your working PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

The cron jobs that you are referencing keep the indexes and links within the Magento system up-to-date, not the software itself.  wget is used to retrieve files and this is not what these cron jobs do.

You really do need to let these cron jobs run, since they do trim and keep ordered all of the entropy that is Magento.

I also think you do not need to specify php.ini explicitly.  Just the path will do.

Comment: I have multiple versions of PHP installed so need to specify WHICH php.ini to use. Cron does not necessarily use the save version of PHP as the www user. You are right, these cron items are necessariy for Magento housekeeping. My problem is that I want to guarantee that the same version of php that is used for the www user is also used in cron... but how??? I have many Magento sites installed in an fcgid environment and not all are using the same version of PHP... hence my desire to use wget or cron.